# Angular 2 : ViewChild is undefined on parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following error :

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'test_id' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'test_id' of undefined

The errror is trigger on this line:

```
    console.log('after view init testList', this.productList.test_id);
```

I saw a lot of posts but all of them seems outdated and most of them are saying that I have to use a function ngAfterViewInit which I did.
I have a clic action that triggers updateTestId and I want to pass this id to my child view ProductListComponent.
Here is my parent component :

```
import { Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import {Test,TestData} from './testService';

import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {ProductListComponent} from '../../components/product/list/productList.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'test-list',
  templateUrl: './testList.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testList.scss']
})
export class TestListComponent{

  //tests: Test[];
  tests: any[];
  selected_test : number;


  @ViewChild(ProductListComponent)
  private productList: ProductListComponent;

  constructor(protected service: TestData){
    this.service.getData().then((data) => {
      this.tests = data.tests;
      this.source.load(data);
    });


  }

  settings = {
    editable : false,
    actions: {
      add:false,
      edit:false,
      delete:false
  },
  columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
        type: 'number'
      },
      nb_cartons: {
        title: 'Cartons',
        type: 'number'
      },
      nb_items: {
        title: 'Items',
        type: 'number'
      },
      nb_pallets: {
        title: 'Pallets',
        type: 'number'
      },
  };

  //source : Test[];
  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();


  public updateTestId(value:any):void {

    this.selected_test = value.data.id;
    console.log('rowSelect', this.selected_test );
    //console.log(this.productList.test_id)

  }


}
```

And here is my child component :

```
    import { Component,Input,Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {Test} from '../../test/testService';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-list',
  templateUrl: './productList.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productList.scss']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnChanges{

  @Input() test_id : number = null;

  settings = {
    editable : false,
    actions: {
      add:false,
      edit:false,
      delete:false
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
        type: 'number'
      },
      sku: {
        title: 'SKU',
        type: 'string'
      },
      reference: {
        title: 'Reference',
        type: 'string'
      },
      size: {
        title: 'Size',
        type: 'string'
      },
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="ion-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
    }
  };

  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();


  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes['test_id'],changes['test_id'].currentValue);
    console.log('change in child',changes.test_id);
  }

  /*
  @Input()
  set _test_id(id: number) {
    this._test_id = id;
  }

  get test_id(): number { return this._test_id; }
*/

}
```

i use the child selector like this :

```
<test-list></test-list>
<product-list #productList [test_id]="selected_test"></product-list>
```

Comment: test_id ? you haven't define it .... so it will htrow error obvious

Comment: it is defined in my child component here ( I updated my post : 
  @Input() test_id : number = null; )

Comment: Whats the purpose of doing this?

Comment: as said above, my main goal is to pass this test id to my child component. This id is defined on my parent component on click on a line of my list inside parent component

Comment: Can you include the full testList.html in the question? There is no `ngIf` directive in it? If you comment out the problematic line, can you see your child component (ProductListComponent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass data from parent to child you can directly pass

```
<product-list [test_id]="selected_test"></product-list>
```

That's it , nothing more.

There is no need to access it via `@ViewChild`

---

> To detect the changed value over the time from product-list component

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes['test_id'].currentValue);
}
```

**Example :**

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

Things to note :
You need to `implements OnChanges` on child component.

For more detail please read this [doc](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Comment: I tried again your solution but it is not triggering anything on change with my click that sets selected_test . I have log only displayed once on load and it is undefined ( normal at this point)
I did implements OnChanges and added log message in test-list ( on selected_test ) and product-list ( on test_id). 
So the changed value is not detected and I don't know why. I will try again with viewChild except if you have a solution

Comment: Its hould work , please check , there will be some minor issue with code , there no need to use ViewChild.

If you have plunker , please share it here.

Comment: That s exactly what I did and it is not working. It will probably take me few hours to rebuild my code in a plunker as I use ng2-admin to generate my list, I have dependencies and api calls to mock so it is not really easy to create it. I tried several ways ( @input, viewChild...) but I guess I will have to go to the dirty way and save it in session if I havent an explicit solution.

Comment: try console.log(changes['text_id'].currentValue);

Comment: it is undefined, see changes['test_id'] : change in child SimpleChangecurrentValue: undefinedfirstChange: truepreviousValue: undefined . As said on first comment here, the change log is triggered only on load and not triggered on my click. Of course have my log above rowSelect that is triggered on a selection of a row in parent list.

Comment: will you please post the full component code ? in question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147393/discussion-between-nicolas-d-and-vivek-doshi).

Comment: after discussion we noticed that i was using another html to call the 2 components together instead of calling them one by one in their own html file

Answer (score 5):

Add a *[template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) name* to the `product-list` in the template

```
<product-list #productList [test_id]="selected_test"></product-list>
```

And reference it by that in the component

```
@ViewChild('productList')
private productList: ProductListComponent;
```

**EDIT:**

In this case **Vivek Doshi** is correct in his answer that you don't need it since you are passing data to the child via `@Input`. But still - if you want to use `ViewChild`, this is a solution :)

Comment: I tried your solution, it is not changing error. It is a good hint because now my ide redirects well to the test_id of productList component instead of searching it but it didnt solved my issue sadly