# Angular 7 - View Child Still Returns as Undefined After Child Component is Initialized

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that is utilizing a View Change subscription to watch for changes in a form checkbox.  When the checkbox changes to true, the child component's form is to be set to disabled and enabled when the checkbox is false. Each time I try to call the View Child function when the checkbox is checked, I am returned the following error: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableForm' of undefined.

The posts that I've found on here discussing this issue seem to point to the child component being hidden by an ngIf, but this is not the case in my instance.

I've console logged the various Angular life cycle events, NgOnInit, NgAfterViewInit, createForm(), etc and they all return when the form is initialized.  I'm also able to pass a value into the child component that will disable the child form field on Init, so that part is working.  But I cannot get the View Child to work through the same component instance.

Here I initialize my View Child:

```
@ViewChild('effectiveDateComponent') effectiveDateComponent: any;
```

Here I am listening for form changes in my checkbox (called "futureDelete":

```
    this.editForm.get('futureDelete').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if (val === false) {
        this.effectiveDateComponent.disableForm();
        this.deleteButtonDisableFlag = false;
      }
      if (val === true) {
        this.effectiveDateComponent.enableForm();
        this.deleteButtonDisableFlag = true;
        this.editForm.controls.dateSearch.get('date').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
          if (val) {
            this.deleteButtonDisableFlag = false;
          }
          if (!val) {
            this.deleteButtonDisableFlag = true;
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Here is my HTML component call:

```
<app-datetimepicker #effectiveDateComponent [disabled]="true" [dateField]="'effectiveDate'" (dateEmit)="receiveDateEmit($event)" [placeholder]="'yyyy-mm-dd'">Effective Date</app-datetimepicker>
```

I expect either the function disableForm() or enableForm() to be called, but instead I get the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableForm' of undefined.

Comment: can you try calling this method once the child component is initialized..i.e may be call it in ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: I THINK that I am calling it after the child is initialized.  I've set up console logs at the various life cycle hooks, and they're all firing.

Comment: Try calling your function inside a settimeout function?                
 setTimeout(() => yourfunction(),1000)

Comment: I had already tried exactly that, and I still threw the same error.

Comment: huh okay!!..as a workaround what you can do is, have a variable in the parent component which can be set in your function which subcribes to valuechanges of checkbox.This variable can be set as a input to the child component and In the child component you need to subscribe to ngOnChanges on the input variable to see if the variable has changed and then use it  to enable and disable form. similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702370/angular-2-viewchild-is-undefined-on-parent?rq=1

Comment: Ashok, your work around works!  It seems in this case that I didn't even need to be using View Child?

Comment: yes it is not required in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround what you can do is, have a variable in the parent component which can be set in your function which subcribes to valuechanges of checkbox.This variable can be set as a input to the child component and In the child component you need to subscribe to ngOnChanges on the input variable to see if the variable has changed and then use it to enable and disable form. similar to this: [Angular 2 : ViewChild is undefined on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702370/angular-2-viewchild-is-undefined-on-parent?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this by component. If your `<app-datetimepicker>` component class is `class AppDatetimepicker`, then you could try this:

```
@ViewChild(AppDatetimepicker) effectiveDateComponent: AppDatetimepicker;
```

Comment: that returns the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: effectiveDateComponent is not defined. I think the quotes are syntactically necessary?

Comment: you're right. i posted before i read the whole answer. i updated immediately after, but you must have seen before i updated.

Comment: It's no problem, I appreciate the help.  Your edited code returns my original error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableForm' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is executed before the `ViewChild` is resolved maybe you just have to add a `if (this.effectiveDateComponent){}` around both the `enableForm()` and `disableForm();` methods

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It causes the entire block of code to be skipped, which I guess proves your point that the View Child isn't resolved?

Comment: maybe you have a *ngIf in your template file ?

Comment: There are 10 of them in my template file, but I'm pretty certain that none are enclosing the component in question.

Comment: Where does the portion of code: this.editForm.get('futureDelete').valueChanges is executed ? In the constructor ? The ngOnInit() method ?

Comment: It's called in ngOnInit().

Comment: Could you try to call it in the ngAfterViewInit() method?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place this subscription inside the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

Description of ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook, according to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views / the view that a directive is in.